# Chrome version 57.0.2987.133 blocks asp.net page from loading after post back

Tags: c#, google-chrome, webforms

When I click save on my asp.net web application, version 57.0.2987.133 of chrome gives blocks the page from loading. It gives following error:

"Chrome detected unusual code on this page and blocked it to protect your personal information (for example, passwords, phone numbers, and credit cards)."

I have attached the screen shot.

[Chrome Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtO4N.jpg)

Here is what I am doing.

In a JavaScript function, I trigger the click event of a hidden link button

```js
function SubmitPage(){
document.getElementById('lnkSave').click();
}

//Code Behind Event Handler

protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  // here I save the data, after saving data I populate controls
  PopulateControlsData();
}

private void PopulateControlsData(){
  // This function populates front end
  // controls e.g. drop downs and text fields etc.
}
```

```html
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSave" Style="display:none;" runat="server" OnClick="Save_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

Earlier version of chrome was working fine. When I remove PopulateControlsData() function from my code, everything works fine. Is this a bug in Chrome version 57.0.2987.133 or is there anything wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of code exists inside `PopulateControlsData` method? Seems that XSS audit messed up with similar case on this Chrome bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706038. If you're using local development, try adding `--disable-xss-auditor` on Chrome shortcut to find out.

Comment: --disable-xss-auditor on chrome shortcut solved the problem for me. Isn't it risky to disable the xss?

Comment: The XSS auditing mechanism on Chrome version 57 and later seems to be bugged at this time, since other server-side languages also suffering the same problem. As a temporary fix, you may specify `x-xss-protection: 0` header has inserted before doing postback with `PopulateControlsData` method (even if it still insecure though).

Comment: I have controls like drop down lists, text boxes, images and a div which basically acts as an editing area. User can add controls to the editing area. 

After saving the data, I call this function **PopulateControlsData()** . This function gets data of respective control from database and populate the control.

Some of the controls have html which might be suspicious to chrome 57.0.2987.133. For example

I populate an image from DB to front end like this
`<img src="image.jpg" onkeydown="ShowImgMenu();" onrightclick="RemoveImageMenu();"/>`

I am not sure if this is causing the problem.

Comment: The HTML parts from editing area may triggering XSS auditor error due to security checks used in XSS auditor module. Seems that you need to check in code-behind which browser agent used by client to send GET request, if Chrome 57.0.2987 is detected then `x-xss-protection: 0` automatically sent when performing postback.

Comment: I eventually found the code that was creating problem. In code behind, I was setting a front end variable that had VB Script (as a string). By removing the statement my problem was resolved.
Thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
Response.AppendHeader("X-XSS-Protection","0")
```

to disable the X-SSS protection on the browser